# Преимущества шаблонов

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Вскоре планирую изучать шаблоны. Но перед этим хотелось бы узнать конкретно, можно ли быть хорошим (и востребованным) программистом, не зная их. Больше интересуют шаблоны по C#, WPF. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, помагают ли они и на сколько?

Comment: Шаблоны проектирования? ( http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблон_проектирования )

Comment: Может быть @semenvx27 имел ввиду [Generic Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f(v=vs.80).aspx)? Поскольку шаблоны проектирования не привязаны к конкретным языкам.

Comment: Шаблонов куча, да только что по С# учить? Дорос ли я вообще до них?

Comment: Если у вас возникают такие вопросы, то нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Шаблоны проектирования существуют не
     только в C#, как вы думаете. Они
     могут быть реализованы во всех
     объектных языках программирования,
     т.е в тех, где поддерживаются самые
     распространенные единицы ООП - класс,
     инкапсуляция, наследование и
     полиморфизм. В некоторых шаблонах не
     обязательно используются все 4 штуки.
- Вы могли уже использовать те или иные
     шаблоны, даже не подозревая об этом. Т.е. Вы
     могли применять элементы или целые
     шаблоны  в реализации
     классов или "связке"(группе) классов.
     Поэтому, вопрос, скорее, в том,
     понимаете ли Вы ООП. Шаблоны тоже
     не придумывались людьми на пустом
     месте, все они(почти все) были
     взяты из хорошо построенных программ,
     из реализации объектной части.
- И наконец, вам не стоит учить все шаблоны проектирования, вам достаточно знать самые основные: [**Singleton,**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E4%E8%ED%EE%F7%EA%E0_%28%F8%E0%E1%EB%EE%ED_%EF%F0%EE%E5%EA%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%FF%29) **[Команда,](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)** **[Стратегия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)**, **[Адаптер](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)**

Comment: ИМХО, `publisher-subscriber, observer, iterator` куда более часто встречаемые паттерны, чем адаптер или команда

Comment: Все паттерны полезны, @Spectre. Мне показалось, что приведенные мною паттерны наиболее используемые, вы думаете иначе...и это правильно! Ведь данное мнение может зависеть от того, в какой конкретно области работает человек, имхо.

Comment: @Spectre, если не секрет, чем отличаются первые 2 паттерна приведенные вами?)

Comment: - **observer:** так называемый `subject` регистрирует(`registerObserver()`) у себя некоторый объект - `observer` - фактически получая ссылку на этот объект(хотя их может быть и несколько), и где-то в своих методах вызывает какой-то метод этого объекта, допустим `update()`. объект `observer` же, при вызове метода `update()` выполняет соответствующую логику обновления

Comment: - **publisher-subsriber:** `subscriber` всего лиш добавляет в массив функций ``publisher`а`` некоторый код для опр. события(`subscribe("eventName", function(){...}`), который будет вызван в контексте ``subscriber`a`` со всеми остальнымы функциями этого события методом `publish("eventName")`

события(`event`) в C# фактически являются реализаций данного паттерна:

    someObj.eventName += (s, e)=>...; 

и есть `subscribe`

Comment: @Spectre ну да, просто разная реализация паттерна наблюдатель. В общем тут по ходу бесполезно спорить со "знатоками"

Comment: могу предположить, что эти различия пошли из-за языков, в которых функции не являются объектами, в связи с чем их нельзя передать в метод `subscribe` и приходится передавать целиком объекты

Answer (score 0):

Шаблоны то существуют не только в C#. Однако в шарпе многие из них реализованы на уровне языка. Могу посоветовать книгу [Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785932861974&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) (автор для меня авторитетен, но именно эту книгу не читал).

Comment: Хорошо, на выходных почитаю. Никто вижу не сомневается, что они нужны. Значит, они действительно нужны

Comment: Еще интересная книга по паттернам
[Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования][1]


  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/

Comment: а как же свежак [Фриман и Фриман. Паттерны проектирования](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144995/)

Comment: @Spectre про свежак смешная шутка (хотя если рассматривать книгу GoF, то да). И просто про книгу которую посоветовал, она учитывает особенности языка. (а книги из комментов имею в наличии и обе отличные)

Comment: @Iranda чем Вам не понравилось "дядюшки Боба"? Почитайте хоть его книгу "Чистый код" и поймете почему я так назвал.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибаются все по-разному. А правильное решение, как правило, одно. Когда множество людей, набив кучу шишек, пришли порознь к одному решению, это стало шаблоном.
Чтоб не набивать свои шишки и сэкономить время надо знать решения распостраненных задач.

Comment: Это не всегда так...